# Facebook Graph API Pagination - Facebook4j - persisting the since and until

Tags: java, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-java-api

I have been using Facebook4j for a Facebook graph API related requirement and my requirement is quite simple.

**Requirement** : I need search Facebook objects (all public objects- posts/comments/pages/ etc..) for given keywords frequently and persist all results into the db.

**Problem** : Although the requirement looks straight forward I am stuck in handling pagination of the results and calling the API later without losing any items ( posts/pages/comments ) in the consecutive calls to the API.

Doing some research I have found graph API provide several Pagination methods and Cursor based is the best and recommended. But unfortunately cursor based search is not available for all kind of objects. So I had to choose time-based pagination which uses until and since parameters.

**Q1.Is my decision is correct?**

Following is a sample previous and next URLs I get when I do a search API call using Facebook4j

```
 previous = https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?limit=200q=infographic&access_token=
           [ACCESS_TOKEN]&since=1400152500&__previous=1, 
 next = https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?limit=200&q=infographic&access_token=
            [ACCESS_TOKEN]&until=1399983583
```

Say I did a API call and using the Facebook4j API method then I should be able to use
fetch next method and continue.

```
 facebook.fetchNext()
```

But when ever I get an exception in my application OR at the point there are no further results I assume that I should be able to persist since/until values and use them for later API calls in the future and continue getting search results from where I stopped last time.

**Q2. Is the assumption regarding the pagination correct ?**

So I am assuming that my future API calls would be something similar to the below. I am not sure whether to use 'since' or 'until'.

**Q3.Is the way I call the API below to continue searching from a previous search is fine ?**

```
 ResponseList<JSONObject> results = facebook.search("KEYWORD",new Reading().limit(200).until("1399983583"));
```

Also I am not sure whether these results are paginated in such a way I get the newest result set when I use the "NEXT url" / fetchnext() provided ?

**Q4.Please clarify me on now the NEXT url provided exactly works in terms of pagination and future API calls?**

If my above approaches are wrong, please suggest the best practices which I should follow to handle this requirement.

Comment: Any guide on this regard would be really helpful